Problems adding individual min/max to error bars in tikzpicture
the following code was mainly done by Claude. It almost does the things I desire, but one thing is not working properly. I want to have error bars for each thicker point/circle, but in my case the error bars don't show the standard deviation, but rather the min and max, so there can be different differences between the actual point and the bar above and below. However, my code always goes the same distance in both directions. How do I adjust my code to achieve this? Also, the error bars and the connecting lines should have less occupancy.
This is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \definecolor{customRed2}{HTML}{feb77e}    
        \definecolor{customgreen2}{HTML}{251255} 
        \definecolor{customyellow2}{HTML}{b73779}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize Total Undercoverage},
                xmin=1, xmax=10,
                ymin=0, ymax=100,
                grid=major,
                title={a)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.2)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
                legend style={
                    font=\footnotesize,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    draw=black,
                    rounded corners=3pt,
                    inner xsep=3pt,
                    inner ysep=2pt,
                    column sep=5pt,
                },
                legend to name=commonlegend
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (1,20) +- (0,2)
                (2,25) +- (0,2)
                (3,30) +- (0,2)
                (4,35) +- (0,2)
                (5,40) +- (0,2)
                (6,45) +- (0,2)
                (7,50) +- (0,2)
                (8,55) +- (0,2)
                (9,60) +- (0,2)
                (10,65) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1}
            
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,25) +- (0,2)
                (2,30) +- (0,2)
                (3,35) +- (0,2)
                (4,40) +- (0,2)
                (5,45) +- (0,2)
                (6,50) +- (0,2)
                (7,55) +- (0,2)
                (8,60) +- (0,2)
                (9,65) +- (0,2)
                (10,70) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,30) +- (0,2)
                (2,35) +- (0,2)
                (3,40) +- (0,2)
                (4,45) +- (0,2)
                (5,50) +- (0,2)
                (6,55) +- (0,2)
                (7,60) +- (0,2)
                (8,65) +- (0,2)
                (9,70) +- (0,2)
                (10,75) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,35) +- (0,2)
                (2,40) +- (0,2)
                (3,45) +- (0,2)
                (4,50) +- (0,2)
                (5,55) +- (0,2)
                (6,60) +- (0,2)
                (7,65) +- (0,2)
                (8,70) +- (0,2)
                (9,75) +- (0,2)
                (10,80) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2}
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,40) +- (0,2)
                (2,45) +- (0,2)
                (3,50) +- (0,2)
                (4,55) +- (0,2)
                (5,60) +- (0,2)
                (6,65) +- (0,2)
                (7,70) +- (0,2)
                (8,75) +- (0,2)
                (9,80) +- (0,2)
                (10,85) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3}
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,45) +- (0,2)
                (2,50) +- (0,2)
                (3,55) +- (0,2)
                (4,60) +- (0,2)
                (5,65) +- (0,2)
                (6,70) +- (0,2)
                (7,75) +- (0,2)
                (8,80) +- (0,2)
                (9,85) +- (0,2)
                (10,90) +- (0,2)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=1, xmax=10,
                ymin=0, ymax=100,
                grid=major,
                title={b)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.2)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,80) +- (0,2)
                (2,70) +- (0,2)
                (3,60) +- (0,2)
                (4,50) +- (0,2)
                (5,40) +- (0,2)
                (6,30) +- (0,2)
                (7,25) +- (0,2)
                (8,20) +- (0,2)
                (9,15) +- (0,2)
                (10,10) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,85) +- (0,2)
                (2,85) +- (0,2)
                (3,85) +- (0,2)
                (4,85) +- (0,2)
                (5,85) +- (0,2)
                (6,85) +- (0,2)
                (7,85) +- (0,2)
                (8,85) +- (0,2)
                (9,85) +- (0,2)
                (10,85) +- (0,2)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{-0.8cm}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize Total Undercoverage},
                xmin=1, xmax=10,
                ymin=0, ymax=100,
                grid=major,
                title={c)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.2)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,25) +- (0,2)
                (2,30) +- (0,2)
                (3,35) +- (0,2)
                (4,40) +- (0,2)
                (5,45) +- (0,2)
                (6,50) +- (0,2)
                (7,55) +- (0,2)
                (8,60) +- (0,2)
                (9,65) +- (0,2)
                (10,70) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,30) +- (0,2)
                (2,35) +- (0,2)
                (3,40) +- (0,2)
                (4,45) +- (0,2)
                (5,50) +- (0,2)
                (6,55) +- (0,2)
                (7,60) +- (0,2)
                (8,65) +- (0,2)
                (9,70) +- (0,2)
                (10,75) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,35) +- (0,2)
                (2,40) +- (0,2)
                (3,45) +- (0,2)
                (4,50) +- (0,2)
                (5,55) +- (0,2)
                (6,60) +- (0,2)
                (7,65) +- (0,2)
                (8,70) +- (0,2)
                (9,75) +- (0,2)
                (10,80) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,40) +- (0,2)
                (2,45) +- (0,2)
                (3,50) +- (0,2)
                (4,55) +- (0,2)
                (5,60) +- (0,2)
                (6,65) +- (0,2)
                (7,70) +- (0,2)
                (8,75) +- (0,2)
                (9,80) +- (0,2)
                (10,85) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,45) +- (0,2)
                (2,50) +- (0,2)
                (3,55) +- (0,2)
                (4,60) +- (0,2)
                (5,65) +- (0,2)
                (6,70) +- (0,2)
                (7,75) +- (0,2)
                (8,80) +- (0,2)
                (9,85) +- (0,2)
                (10,90) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,50) +- (0,2)
                (2,55) +- (0,2)
                (3,60) +- (0,2)
                (4,65) +- (0,2)
                (5,70) +- (0,2)
                (6,75) +- (0,2)
                (7,80) +- (0,2)
                (8,85) +- (0,2)
                (9,90) +- (0,2)
                (10,95) +- (0,2)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=1, xmax=10,
                ymin=0, ymax=100,
                grid=major,
                title={d)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.2)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=yellow,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,80) +- (0,2)
                (2,70) +- (0,2)
                (3,60) +- (0,2)
                (4,50) +- (0,2)
                (5,40) +- (0,2)
                (6,30) +- (0,2)
                (7,25) +- (0,2)
                (8,20) +- (0,2)
                (9,15) +- (0,2)
                (10,10) +- (0,2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=green,
                mark=square*,
                dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (1,85) +- (0,2)
                (2,85) +- (0,2)
                (3,85) +- (0,2)
                (4,85) +- (0,2)
                (5,85) +- (0,2)
                (6,85) +- (0,2)
                (7,85) +- (0,2)
                (8,85) +- (0,2)
                (9,85) +- (0,2)
                (10,85) +- (0,2)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{0.35cm}
    \centering
    \ref{commonlegend}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Incidentally, who or what is Claude?

Something similar to ChatGPT. Claude.ai

Thanks for providing this piece of information. I was starting to wonder why the tikzpicture environments had been placed inside subfigure  environments, with the latter not actually doing anything that might be deemed essential. (A subfigure is essentially a minipage that's been trained to know what to do if it encounters a \caption statement. Since there are no \caption statements in the subfigure environments, one might as well be using minipage environments.)

Well actually I have a caption but I didn't include it since I didn't knew it was significant. Let me fix my code. Sorry for that

@Mico Done! Sorry

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot[
red,
mark=square*,
error bars/.cd,
  y dir=both,
  y explicit,
]
coordinates {
(1,50) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(2,55) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(3,60) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(4,65) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(5,70) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(6,75) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(7,80) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(8,85) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(9,90) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
(10,95) += (0,2) -= (0,6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


